# Getting the "unread" part of a string being read with Clojure's read-string

Tags: clojure, tokenize

Clojure's (read-string) is really useful.

eg.

```
(read-string "{:a 1 :b 2} {:c 3 :d 4} [1 2 3]")
```

will give me the first object, the `{:a 1 :b 2}`

But how can I get the rest of string ie. `"{:c 3 :d 4} [1 2 3]"`

What's the reader equivalent of `rest` or `drop` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not very idiomatic but straightforward

```
(->> (str "(" "{:a 1 :b 2} {:c 3 :d 4} [1 2 3]" ")") 
     (read-string))
```

then access to individual elements (you can also use brackets)

Comment: Yes, that works.  Though it is kind of weird to have to do it that way ... cheers

Comment: The idiomatic and complete answer - which does not require manual changes to the input - has been provided by Michal Marczyk

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the string in a `StringReader`, then wrap that in a `PushbackReader`, then `read` from that reader multiple times.

NB. the example below uses `clojure.edn/read`, as that is an edn-only reader meant for dealing with pure data; `clojure.core/read` is primarily meant for reading code and should *never* be used with untrusted inputs.

```
(require '[clojure.edn :as edn])

(def s "{:a 1 :b 2} {:c 3 :d 4} [1 2 3]")

;; Normally one would want to use with-open to close the reader,
;; but here we don't really care and we don't want to accidentally
;; close it before consuming the result:
(let [rdr (java.io.PushbackReader. (java.io.StringReader. s))
      sentinel (Object.)]      ; ← or just use ::eof as sentinel
  (take-while #(not= sentinel %)
              (repeatedly #(edn/read {:eof sentinel} rdr))))
;= ({:a 1, :b 2} {:c 3, :d 4} [1 2 3])
```

Answer (score 2):

ClojureScript version of what should be the accepted answer by [https://stackoverflow.com/users/232707/michał-marczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/232707/micha%C5%82-marczyk)

```clj
(require '[cljs.reader :as rdr])
(require '[cljs.tools.reader.reader-types :as reader-types])

(def s "{:a 1 :b 2} {:c 3 :d 4} [1 2 3]")

(let [pbr (reader-types/string-push-back-reader s)
      sentinel ::eof]
    (take-while #(not= sentinel %)
        (repeatedly #(rdr/read {:eof sentinel} pbr))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list within the string, you can preserve it via options given to `read-string`-

```
(def str-list "({:a 1 :b 2} {:c 3 :d 4} [1 2 3])")

(read-string {:read-cond :preserve} str-list)
;;=> ({:a 1 :b 2} {:c 3 :d 4} [1 2 3])
```

The source for the available options can be found in the doc string the of [read function](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3639), i.e. `(source read)`from the REPL.

Comment: `read-cond` has nothing to do with this at all. There are no reader conditionals in any of the example inputs.

Comment: You are correct insofar as there are no reader conditionals. However, the option hash allows the preservation of valid forms in the string, which is the functionality that the OP is after, with no additional libs. Perhaps `:read-cond` is too narrow of a name, but it parses the string according to what the question is looking for.